# SQL Server XQuery - Find the original data type

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery, xquery-sql

In the following code, I want to check if column is a Number. If it is - fill it with leading zeros.

Is there anyway using XML XQuery to check the original data type (int)
of the column?

```
declare @T table (string nchar(10), id int)

insert @T
select 'test1', 1

insert @T
select 'test2', 2

declare @X xml

SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON

set @X = (select * from @T order by id for xml path('row'), root('root'))

SELECT (
    STUFF(
    (
        SELECT ';' + v.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
        FROM r.nodes('*') AS B(v)
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'')
    ) as [OUTPUT]
FROM @x.nodes('/root/row') AS A(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you know your table you should not use a generical approach, if you do not have a good reason to do so.

### What you probably should do is this

Include the formatted value into your XML. This allows you, to carry both information within the structure: typed and formatted.

```
declare @T table (string nvarchar(10), id int)

insert @T values
 ('test1', 1)
,('test2', 22)

declare @x xml = (select string
                        ,REPLACE(STR(id,8),' ','0') AS [id/@formatted]
                        ,id 
                  from @T 
                  order by id for xml path('row'), root('root'),TYPE)

SELECT (
    STUFF(
    (
        SELECT ';' + r.value('(string/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') 
             + ';' + r.value('(id/@formatted)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'')
    ) as [OUTPUT]
FROM @x.nodes('/root/row') AS A(r);
```

### If you need the dynamic approach - look at this

```
declare @T table (string nchar(10), id int)

insert @T values
 ('test1', 1)
,('test2', 2)

declare @X xml = (select * from @T order by id for xml path('row'), root('root'))

select @x;
```

The first thing you see, that you - probably want to use `NVARCHAR(10)` instead of `NCHAR(10)`. You might use `LTRIM()` too:

```
<root>
  <row>
    <string>test1     </string>
    <id>1</id>
  </row>
  <row>
    <string>test2     </string>
    <id>2</id>
  </row>
</root>
```

### Now I start from scratch with `NVARCHAR(10)`

```
declare @T2 table (string nvarchar(10), id int);

insert @T2 values
 ('test1', 1)
,('test2', 22);

declare @X2 xml = (select * from @T2 order by id for xml path('row'), root('root'));
```

--First try is with `ISNUMERIC` and `CASE WHEN`

```
SELECT (
    STUFF(
    (
        SELECT ';' + CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(v.value('.','nvarchar(max)'))=1
                          THEN REPLACE(STR(v.value('.','int'),8),' ','0')
                          ELSE v.value('.','nvarchar(max)') END
        FROM r.nodes('*') AS B(v)
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'')
    ) as [OUTPUT]
FROM @x2.nodes('/root/row') AS A(r);
```

But: There are some character formats (scientific notations), which can be taken as numeric incidentically.
Add this to your table and try again

```
,('3d2',333) --breaks, because SELECT ISNUMERIC('3d2'),ISNUMERIC('1e1') returns 1 (for both)
```

### Other/better approaches

If you are [using SQL-Server 2012 or higher, you can use `TRY_CAST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql), which will return NULL instead of an error

```
SELECT (
    STUFF(
    (
        SELECT ';' + CASE WHEN TRY_CAST(v.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS INT) IS NOT NULL 
                          THEN REPLACE(STR(v.value('.','int'),8),' ','0')
                          ELSE v.value('.','nvarchar(max)') END
        FROM r.nodes('*') AS B(v)
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'')
    ) as [OUTPUT]
FROM @x2.nodes('/root/row') AS A(r);
```

Another option might the the explicit XQuery cast ([Find possible XQuery functions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-functions-against-the-xml-data-type))

```
SELECT (
    STUFF(
    (
        SELECT ';' + v.query('let $nd:=string(./text()[1])
                                 ,$nr:=concat("00000000",string($nd cast as xs:int?)) 
                              return if(string-length($nr)=8) 
                                     then $nd 
                                     else substring($nr,string-length($nr)-7)').value('.','nvarchar(max)')
        FROM r.nodes('*') AS B(v)
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'')
    ) as [OUTPUT]
FROM @x2.nodes('/root/row') AS A(r);
```

### UPDATE

XML is not aware of an *underlying type* unless you specify a schema. Look at this:

```
declare @T2 table (string nvarchar(10), id int)

insert @T2 values
 ('test1', 1)
,('test2', 22)
,('1',333)

declare @x2 xml = (select * from @T2 order by id for xml raw('row'), root('root'),xmlschema)
select @x2;

<root>
  <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sqltypes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" targetNamespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet1" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes/sqltypes.xsd" />
    <xsd:element name="row">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:attribute name="string">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="1033" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth">
              <xsd:maxLength value="10" />
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:attribute>
        <xsd:attribute name="id" type="sqltypes:int" />
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
  </xsd:schema>
  <row xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet1" string="test1" id="1" />
  <row xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet1" string="test2" id="22" />
  <row xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet1" string="1" id="333" />
</root>
```

In this case you might ask the schema for the underlying type. But - if I get you correctly - you want to look at **any value if it might be a number**. This works as shown, but is extremely dangerous...

Comment: Thank for your professional answer.
First, I need the spaces. That 's why I used 'nchar'
Second, all your options, Check if the value is numeric.
So, if I have a numeric value in text field, It is identified as a number.

For example:

declare @T table (string nchar(10), id int)

insert @T values
 ('test1', 1)
,('2', 2)
etc.

The result:
test1     ;00000001
00000002;00000002

Comment: @inon, Besides the fact, that I think, that you might be following the wrong path (Read about the [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)), I have some questions: What is your SQL Server's version? Why do you need **fixed width *and* a delimiter**? Did you really check my approaches? The last two will return exactly the way you seem to want it...

Comment: :) It raly dangerous, their is no build-in xquery function to get the datatype? maybe, we first need to store at temp table the data-types of table @t and join it in the query?

Comment: @inon, Really! Re-think your approach! First of all: Why don't you **answer my questions** (see my comment above)? 2) Did you really **try my approaches**? They work as expected... 3) **There is a *built-in* way** with the explicit cast. 4) You seem to **store numbers and strings in the same columnn. There is no *data-type*** you could get... Nothing more than a string based *casteability* or *parseability*... I think, that there is a deep misconception of XML and data types...

Comment: @inon Is this question solved? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: If this question is solved, it would be very kind of you, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Since you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!